# Github расширение для Visual studio. Можно ли пользоваться Git через командную строку?

Tags: visual-studio, git

Или же нужно отдельно устанавливать git for windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь про «GitHub Extension for Visual Studio» https://visualstudio.github.com/, то на [скриншоте](https://visualstudio.github.com/images/install-the-extension.png) видно, что при установке Git for Windows ставится в обязательном порядке.

То есть отдельно ставить не нужно, он уже будет, и командная строка тоже.

Возможно, потребуется откорректировать переменную среды PATH, а может инсталлятор это сделает сам.

Comment: Проблема была в том что даже без установки расширения базовые возможности этого расширения присутствовали в Visual Studio 2017